# What is the full script to extract sequences from fasta file by using Ids in text file in python 3 and pycharm?

Tags: python, fasta

I have a fasta file (gene.fasta)with sequences with names patterns:

```
>Hsc_gene_9627.t1
ATGGCACGCATTTTCCTCATTCTTTTATTGCTGCACAACATCTGCTGTGCAGCCGCTTCA
TTGCTCATTTTGAATGCCGTTACATTGGAGAAGGATGCTAATGATTATGCCGTTGGCGAT
```

and I have the Ids in text file (seq.txt) which are not the exact as in the fasta file:

```
HSC_gene_996
HSC_gene_9734
and some of the names came as 
HSC_gene_996|HSC_gene_9734
```

How can extract the sequences?
I am not experienced in python so please use python for dummies language :)
Thank you in advance

Comment: Does it have to be python? There are far easier ways using only bash, etc.

Comment: I just have python in my computer, if there is please help me, I tried to find some online tools but it didn't work

Comment: You may want to try Joe Healey's bioinfo-tools repository. [This script](https://github.com/jrjhealey/bioinfo-tools/blob/master/fastafetcher.py) looks like the one to use.

Comment: To second @RamRS, that script should work indeed - provided your IDs are exact full or substring matches (excluding the `>`). It's been a while since I used it, so if it could be tweaked to be more useful, I'm happy to take suggestions. Whilst I love `bash` etc., I'd probably disagree with NatWH that it is _easier_ than using something like `biopython` which is purpose built for this.

Comment: OP's problem seems to be their platform. Python excels in being a cross-platform solution, hence OP looking for Python based solutions makes sense.

Comment: Hi @SamerHabash, i can write it in python. Can you give an example where it is supposed to hit (i suppose Hsc_gene_9627.t1 and Hsc_gene_9627) and instances where it doesn't?

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf, that would be great thank you. All my target sequences IDs are like (HSC_gene_996) in a text file which are missing the (.t1 and .t2 in some cases). in the fasta file they are all ending with ( .t1 or some cases .t2- like this one :  >Hsc_gene_9627.t1 )

Answer (score 1):

For example, the fasta are like these:

```
gene.fasta:

>Hsc_gene_9627.t1
ATGGCACGCATTTTCCTCATTCTTTTATTGCTGCACA
ACATCTGCTGTGCAGCCGCTTCA
>Hsc_gene_9627.t2
GGGGTTTTCCCC
>Hsc_gene_962.t1
AGTCGTCAGTCAGTAGTCGC

seq.txt:

HSC_gene_9627
HSC_gene_9734 
HSC_gene_996|HSC_gene_9734
```

We use a few modules, read in the fasta:

```
import re
from Bio import SeqIO                                                                 
records = list(SeqIO.parse("gene.fasta","fasta"))
```

Read in the list:

```
seq = [i.rstrip().lower() for i in open('seq.txt').readlines()]
```

Here I use two functions, one to write fasta files, and the other to format the header for comparison:

```
def fasta_out(rec):
    return(">"+str(rec.description)+"\n"+str(rec.seq))

def format(rec):
    return re.sub("[.][^ ]*$","",rec.description).lower()
```

Define the records to keep:

```
keep = [fasta_out(i) for i in records if format(i) in seq]
```

Write them out:

```
f=open('matched.fasta','w')
f.writelines("\n".join(keep))
f.close()
```

We can check:

```
open('matched.fasta').readlines()                                                          
Out[50]: 
['>Hsc_gene_9627.t1\n',
 'ATGGCACGCATTTTCCTCATTCTTTTATTGCTGCACAACATCTGCTGTGCAGCCGCTTCA\n',
 '>Hsc_gene_9627.t2\n',
 'GGGGTTTTCCCC']
```

Most likely there are some simple while, for loops that does not require modules..

Comment: Thank you very much @StupidWolf